# Comparison b/w TestNg and Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, testng

Comparison b/w TestNg and Cucumber.
On which is a better framework, If goal is to  implement changes and if a project is based on  step wise scenario test cases

Example

1. Get up
2. Set your bed
3. walk towards bathroom
4. brush and shower
5. Ready - Finished a test cases

Goal - If i want to remove the step 3. or add a step after 4.
Which framework supports better to have Cucumber or TesNG currently my company has both... and since its a step wise project using cucumber. But now we are debating on to keep or switch to TesnNG. Also, would like to know which framework is easy to make changes?

Your advices and suggestions will help to decide... Thankyou in advance

Comment: Cucumber lets you write tests in English. TestNG appears to be a standard unit-test framework. So they're really not comparable - they don't serve the same purpose.

Comment: So, if the project UI is a step to step basis scenario test case. Believe,TestNG usage would be depends on or Priority annotations. Where as cucumber won't need as creates a step definition for us. In this aspect.... when any changes needs to be done . Which framework will be easier to implement the changes. Any idea?